# Azure start-up task to run after the website is created

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I've created a start-up task for an Azure website that does the following:

- Creates an AppPool
- Converts a Virtual Directory into a Virtual Application

I've created a powershell script that carries out these tasks.

I've set up the startup element in the Service Definition

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="MyStartup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
    </Task>
</Startup>
```

All good so far.

However, [I've found out, rather late](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx), that:

> IIS may not be fully configured during the startup task stage in the
>   startup process, so role-specific data may not be available.

I take this to mean that the website may not exist on IIS when the powershell script is run. I've tested the script and sure enough it fails because it can't find the virtual directory on IIS.

My question is: Is there a way to ensure the powershell script is run ***after*** the website is created on IIS?

Please note, I don't really want to use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEntryPoint.OnStart` if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We use the OnStart for our products on WebRoles and its not that bad. You can create your own little startup factory that have powershell scripts on blob storage and then when cloud services start they sync the scripts and you can have the configuration stored in blob storage also to which scripts to run. This way its really easy to update and maintain the startup experience for future webroles you might create. But startup tasks will run before IIS is setup.  One our our products we actually clean IIS in the OnStart and do our own website setup from blob storage also.

Comment: @pksorensen the reason I'd didn't want to use OnStart is that depends on C#. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can start processes from c# or run powershell scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the role architecture diagram at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx.  You can see that the startup tasks are executed before IISConfigurator creates the application pool for your website.  This means that the only place you can make modifications to the apppool is in OnStart.

I haven't tried this, but you could create a background type startup task which will let the rest of the startup process (ie. running IISConfigurator) proceed while your startup task is still running, and then within that startup just loop until the virtual directory is detected.

Answer (score 6):

I followed on from @kwill's suggestion and created the following:

Powershell:

```
while(!($myWeb = Get-Website -name "*MyWeb*")){
    Write-Host "Website not installed. Waiting 30 seconds..."
    Start-Sleep 30
}

# Proceed with installation
```

and configuration

```
  <Task commandLine="MyBackground.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background">
  </Task>
```

This works.